# How to erase spaces in paste function to build URL?

Tags: r, url, csv, paste

In advance, thank you for your help.  Essentially, I am scripting a program that builds a URL which will provide a CSV file.  The program asks the user for several inputs and then appends those inputs to the base URL. The problem I am getting is that there is an added space between each of the user inputs when I try to paste them together in the URL.  The problem is in the #Build URL line.

Here is the code

```
 #URL Builder for Yahoo Finance
 #Requests Input from User, Builds URL, downloads csv.file from site
 #Requests are for:
      #Ticker (2-4 letter - character string)
      #Start Month (00 - 11 integer)
      #Start Day (1 - 31 integer)
      #Start Year (Four digit integer)
      #End Month (00 - 11 integer)
      #End Day (1 - 31 integer)
      #End Year (Four digit integer)

 #Functions
      Get_Ticker <- function(){readline("Please enter a Ticker:>>> ")} 
      Get_Month_Begin <- function(){as.numeric(readline("Enter the start month (MM):>>> "))}
      Get_Day_Begin <- function(){as.numeric(readline("Enter the start day (1-31) :>>> "))}
      Get_Year_Begin <- function(){as.numeric(readline("Enter the start year (YYYY) :>>> "))}
      Get_Month_End <- function(){as.numeric(readline("Enter the end month (MM) :>>> "))}
      Get_Day_End <- function(){as.numeric(readline("Enter the end day (1-31) :>>> "))}
      Get_Year_End <- function(){as.numeric(readline("Enter the end year :>>> "))}

 #Function Calls
      Ticker <- Get_Ticker()
      Month_Begin <- Get_Month_Begin()
      Day_Begin <- Get_Day_Begin()
      Year_Begin <- Get_Year_Begin()
      Month_End <- Get_Month_End()
      Day_End <- Get_Day_End()
      Year_End <- Get_Year_End()

 #Build URL
 #Example URL: ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=DVN&a=00&b=1&c=1992&d=11&e=31&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv
      CSV_Base_URL <- "ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="
      CSV_URL_Complete <- paste(CSV_Base_URL,Ticker,"&a=",Month_Begin,"&b=",Day_Begin,"&c=",Year_Begin,"&d=",Month_End,"&e=",Day_End,"&f=",Year_End,"&g=d&ignore=.csv",sep="")

 #Download CSV
      Yahoo_Finance_TBL <- read.csv(CSV_URL_Complete)

 #Write CSV File
      write.csv(Yahoo_Finance_TBL, file="Yahoo_Finance_File", row.names=FALSE)
```

Again, I am very grateful for your assistance.

Respectfully,

Jonathan

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem, for me your code works...

Comment: I don't see any spaces with scalar response to the questions: `[1] "ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=DELL&a=10&b=10&c=2012&d=10&e=31&f=2013&g=dignore=.csv"`. The `sep=""` should take care of this. Note also that `paste0()` is preferred to `paste(...., sep = "")` in newer versions of R (it should be quicker, and saves on the typing of `sep = ""`) :-)

Comment: I updated my code - using collapse="" (notwithstanding the recommendation to use paste0(), which I very much appreciate.  I also had an error in my URL at the end which should read "g=d&ignore=.csv"

I still get the following error:

    Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=DVN&a=11&b=1&c=2005&d=11&e=1&f=2011&g=d&ignore=.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: There are no spaces there! Did you try pasting the URL thus created into a browser to check that the URL is valid?

Comment: And then it dawns - you need to add `"http://"` to the start of the base URL you are using. See my Answer below for further details. You don't need `collapse=""`; the issue was that R had no way of knowing that you were inputting a URL because you didn't specify one of the URL schemes (protocols) that R handles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you don't add `"http://"` to the URL when you build it. How is R supposed to know that this is a URL if you don't tell it. At the moment it is looking for a file with that name on your filesystem in the current working directory.

You want:

```
CSV_Base_URL <- "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="
```

The URL you added to the comment stream on your question *is* valid, so with the above addition R should download and read the CSV from the URL.

`?read.csv has:

```
file:
....
      ‘file’ can also be a complete URL.  (For the supported URL
      schemes, see the ‘URLs’ section of the help for ‘url’.)
```

and that has:

```
 For ‘url’ the description is a complete URL, including scheme
 (such as ‘http://’, ‘ftp://’ or ‘file://’).  Proxies can be
 specified for HTTP and FTP ‘url’ connections: see ‘download.file’.
```

and

```
URLs:

     ‘url’ and ‘file’ support URL schemes ‘http://’, ‘ftp://’ and
     ‘file://’.
```

which explains the issue.

One could speculate that browsers suppressing the protocol from the URL bar (e.g. Chrome) might result in people not knowing that a URL needs more that just the address part?

Comment: Thank you very much Gavin.  I really appreciate the help and the explanation.

Comment: No worries. Glad to help - took a while for me to see the issue here.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid spaces, you need to use paste (sep=""), but you already do that. In  fact, I'm not sure what the problem is, because your code appears to work fine for me. Here is the output when I put your code in my R session:

```
> Ticker <- Get_Ticker()
Please enter a Ticker:>>> GOOG
> Month_Begin <- Get_Month_Begin()
Enter the start month (MM):>>> 01
> Day_Begin <- Get_Day_Begin()
Enter the start day (1-31) :>>> 01
> Year_Begin <- Get_Year_Begin()
Enter the start year (YYYY) :>>> 2013
> Month_End <- Get_Month_End()
Enter the end month (MM) :>>> 02
> Day_End <- Get_Day_End()
Enter the end day (1-31) :>>> 28
> Year_End <- Get_Year_End()
Enter the end year :>>> 2013
> CSV_Base_URL <- "ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="
> CSV_URL_Complete <- paste(CSV_Base_URL,Ticker,"&a=",Month_Begin,"&b=",Day_Begin,"&c=",Year_Begin,"&d=",Month_End,"&e=",Day_End,"&f=",Year_End,"&g=dignore=.csv",sep="")
> CSV_URL_Complete
[1] "ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=01&b=1&c=2013&d=2&e=28&f=2013&g=dignore=.csv"
```

The resulting URL works nicely.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I am getting the following error:

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=DVN&a=11&b=1&c=2005&d=11&e=1&f=2011&g=d&ignore=.csv': No such file or directory